# Modifying a pointer within a function (passing another pointer as a parameter)

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing

I'm having trouble with passing a pointer to a function that is called by another pointer.  I'm trying to modify a pointer (i.e. p1) that calls the function min (i.e. p1->min()) which takes a pointer as a parameter (i.e. p1->min(*p2)).  Note: *p2 isn't modified at all, just passed for its values, for which p1 will be modified based on the values of p2.

**Note: I removed irrelevant code (only inside functions, everything else is as is) to make it easier to read.**

Test.h

```
// Don't worry about the create method, just assume it works
// I'm having issues with the "min" function, more details below

class Test {
    protected:
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > vec;
    public:
        static Test *create(std::string file); // instantiates vec
        void *min(Test *); // modifies vec 
};
```

Test.cc

```
// Don't worry about create (factory method), just assume it works
// "min" is causing compiler errors (see below)

Test *Test::create(string file) { /* instantiates vec with file contents */ }
void *Test::min(const Test *&p) { /* modifies vec */ }
```

main.cc

```
// Main cannot change, this is how it must be implemented
// However, Test.cc and Test.h CAN be modified.

Test *p1 = Test::create("file1");
Test *p2 = Test::create("file2");
p1->min(*p2); // modify p1 based on values of p2, p2 is NOT modified
```

Compiler Errors:

```
fatal error: control reaches end of non-void function
```

What is weird is that its declared void but expecting a return value So, when I do return something it shows up another compiler error

```
fatal error: no viable conversion from return value of type 'Test' to function return type 'void *'
```

I'm so confused on the compile errors.  I'm thinking it has something to do with my declarations.  Note: There is no constructor since the base class must use a factory method while the derived classes use their own constructors, hence the *Test::create and *Test::min.

Please help.

Comment: `Test::min`'s declaration doesn't match it's definition. The arguments are different. And are you sure you want `min` to return `void*`? What's the significance of the return value?

Comment: `void*` is not the same as `void`. Voting to close as typo

Comment: I don't need a return value.  p1->min(*p2) just modifies p1, it doesn't need to return anything.

Comment: *"What is weird is that its declared void "* This is incorrect. Your return type is `void*` not `void`.

Comment: I can't have void func not be void *func because I have pure virtual functions declared in base class, but my derived classes do implement them.  If I return void func, instead of void *func, the compiler complains of unimplemented pure virtual functions.

Comment: I see no base class or derived class. If you aren't going to change the return type then you have to return something.

Comment: its `void* func` , where `void*` is the return type. If you need to return a void pointer then you need to return a void pointer ;)

Comment: If I remove the * after void declaration, I get main.cc: : :fatal error: lvalue reference to type 'Test *' cannot bind to a value of unrelated type 'Test'. note: passing argument to parameter here void min(Test *&) const; 1 error generated.  I already said, main cannot change.

Comment: @N.Colostate You have to return what you declared to return. If your function promises to return a `void*`, then you have to implement it in such a way so that it returns a `void*` Same in `create`, you have to return pointer to `Test`.

Comment: why would you return a `void*` from that method? Maybe you need to fix the base class

Comment: Return a void pointer is the solution.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: You seem to be getting confused about pointers to objects and objects themselves. A `Test*` is not a `Test`, but a pointer to one.

Comment: tbh i think this question is a train wreck. I suggest you to create a new one which does include a [mcve] (ie include your base)

Comment: It's already resolved.  I needed to return a void pointer.

Comment: its resolved in the sense that it compiles, but coding to make the compiler happy will just cause much bigger problems in the long run

Comment: I have parameters to follow, and unfortunately, thats whats causing some responses to question its format.  It is what it is.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is weird is that its declared void

No, it isn't.

```
   Test *Test::create(string file) { /* instantiates vec with file contents */ }
// ^^^^^^ return type is Test*

   void *Test::min(const Test *&p) { /* modifies vec */ }
// ^^^^^^ return type is void*
```

It's unfortunate that you use right-aligned asterisks and ampersands, because it has directly led to your confusion. It looks like you forgot the `*` was there, or thought it was part of the syntax of the function declaration itself (like how, in your question, you've referred to the functions as *"`*Test::create` and `*Test::min`"*).

If you start aligning them to the left (which won't affect the program's semantics, it's just style), your intent and the meaning of types will be clear:

```
Test* Test::create(string file) { /* instantiates vec with file contents */ }
void* Test::min(const Test*& p) { /* modifies vec */ }
```

Now you can easily see at a glance that your return type isn't what you thought it was, and can correct the declaration of `Test::min` (and, possibly, `Test::create`).

*Some people will start going on about how the internal grammar binds the `*` to the name rather than to the type, or about how the left-aligned approach makes it marginally more awkward to get right that really important and frequently-used construct, the multi-variable declaration. Ignore them!*

Speaking more broadly, you have a lot of pointers going on here, and I suggest trying to minimise that. It's only going to lead to unnecessary trouble. *Love objects.*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
void *Test::min(const Test *&p) { /* modifies vec */ }
```

If this function doesn't have a return statement, remove the `*` from `void *`.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution to my issue is that I needed to return a void pointer.  This may cause issues down the road with other things unrelated to this current problem, but this format had specific parameters to follow, which is why I mentioned main cannot change, among other things (including format). Thanks again.

Comment: Just any `void *`? You'd better check what it's used for.

Comment: This doesn't sound right. If your function really did need to return something in a void pointer, you'd already have been doing that. So it sounds like you've just hacked around having used the wrong return type, by returning some bogus/dummy value to shut up the compiler. That is not the proper solution.

Comment: void* Test::min(const Test &p) { // bunch of code; return this; } works for me.  I'm able to modify the pointer using the referenced values from the passed in pointer.  It compiles and works as I wanted it to.

Comment: Like I said, I have certain parameters that I have to follow.  Unfortunately, that means that it may not look efficient or pleasing to look at.  I could make it look more efficient but that would require changing main and adding a constructor in the base class and changing a lot of other things and that would cause problems when were specified to follow certain parameters. All in all, the issue is resolved and it does what I wanted it to.